# laravel 4 - route makes javascript impossible to load from view

Tags: javascript, laravel-4, loading, assets, laravel-routing

my localhost uses a laravel route to open my view, which works:

```
http://localhost/view/stock/equipment
```

Laravel 4 route which returns my view:

```
Route::get('view/stock/equipment', array('uses'=>'App\Controllers\Stock\EquipmentController@getIndex'));
```

my view contains:

```
        {{ HTML::script('js-views/stock/equipment/bootstrap.js') }}
```

Which shows in my html page as:

```
<script src="http://localhost/js-views/stock/equipment/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

But bootstrap.js won't load, when I look using firebug I see it doesn't get loaded from the correct path:

```
 GET http://localhost/view/stock/bootstrap.js   404 Not Found
```

I can see a ' view/stock part ' coming from the laravel route.

the public path is set correctly in Laravel.

How could this be?

Comment: I've noticed that the GET 404 not found is called from within bootstrap.js  - so I should check bootstrap.js  I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what happens if you go to `http://localhost/js-views/stock/equipment/bootstrap.js` in your browser? You should see the javascript file.

Why do you store your javascript together with your stock equipment? Wouldn't it be better to place it in a assets folder? This how I structure my assets (under `laravel/public`):

```
assets/
       css/
       img/
       js/
```

Define the paths in a `assets.php` config file:

```
return array(
    'css' => '/assets/css',
    'img' => '/assets/img',
    'js' => '/assets/js'
);
```

And then use a helper function to return their URLs:

```
class Asset
{
    private static function getUrl($type, $file)
    {
        return URL::to(Config::get('assets.' . $type) . '/' . $file);
    }

    public static function css($file)
    {
        return self::getUrl('css', $file);
    }

    public static function img($file)
    {
        return self::getUrl('img', $file);
    }

    public static function js($file)
    {
        return self::getUrl('js', $file);
    }

}
```

So to display an image I can do this:

```
HTML::image(Asset::img('logo/full.png'), "My website logo")
```

But I let MaxCDN host Bootstrap for me (code from [**Bootstrap website**](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)):

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer hebron. bootstrap.js is a extjs part for a extjs grid I want to display in my blade view.
http://localhost/js-views/stock/equipment/bootstrap.js opens the bootstrap.js no problem here.  I later found that bootstrap is loaded from the blade view..  I think some part(code) in the bootstrap.js is conflicting with the laravel route and then throws a 404 error... So this appears to be a different problem in the end.

Comment: That is why it is unwise to mix your assets with your routes. As I said I too use the Bootstrap framework, but I get it from MaxCDN with the links in my answer, I do not host it myself.

Comment: Thanks hebron, you really understood my problem. Solved. You should earn 1K for this.

Comment: Where to place asset.php file and assets class..please make it clear

Answer (score 0):

save the javascript file to /var/www/yourprojectname/public folder/js

and use `<script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>`